# React 18 upgrade giving.error Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After i upgrade from React 17 to React 18 upgrade. My application is giving below error while saving any file.
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node

Here is my index.js file:-

```
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.module.scss";
import App from "./App";
import envConfig from "./config";
import { LicenseManager } from "ag-grid-enterprise";

const key =
  "CompanyName=Digivizer Pty Ltd,LicensedApplication=Digivizer,LicenseType=SingleApplication,LicensedConcurrentDeveloperCount=2,LicensedProductionInstancesCount=1,AssetReference=AG-016424,ExpiryDate=23_June_2022_[v2]_MTY1NTkzODgwMDAwMA==1cfa1541ae24331badfe71a43feb643c";
LicenseManager.setLicenseKey(key);

const intercomSettings = {
  app_id: envConfig.REACT_APP_INTERCOM_APP_ID,
};

/* eslint-disable no-inner-declarations*/
// prettier-ignore
(function (intercomSettings) { var w = window; var ic = w.Intercom; if (typeof ic === "function") { ic('reattach_activator'); ic('update', intercomSettings); } else { var d = document; var i = function () { i.c(arguments) }; i.q = []; i.c = function (args) { i.q.push(args) }; w.Intercom = i; function l() { var s = d.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = 'https://widget.intercom.io/widget/' + envConfig.INTERCOM_APP_ID; var x = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x); } if (w.attachEvent) { w.attachEvent('onload', l); } else { w.addEventListener('load', l, false); } } })();
/* eslint-enable no-inner-declarations*/
window.Intercom("boot", intercomSettings);

const container = document.getElementById("root");

const root = createRoot(container); // createRoot(container!) if you use TypeScript

root.render(<App />);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}
```

Comment: Just posting a clip of code it's not really enough for people on SO to help.   I would at least post the call stack from your console too.   PS:  `ExpiryDate=23_June_2022`  Looks like your `ag-grid-enterprise` has expired.